# How can I change/modify variable's values while code running using Cubeide?

Tags: debugging, stm32, keil, stm32cubeide

I'm using Keil IDE to program stm32 microcontrollers,
Keil IDE allows to change variable's value "while code running" **without breakpoints.**
I want to use Cubeide instead of Keil.
I can use live expression tool for watching values "while code running" but I can't change values "while code running", I bought Stlink and Segger but I couldn't change the values "while code running".
How can I change/modify variable's values "while code running" using Cubeide ?.

[This is my debug screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/68gKN.png)

Comment: you can. At least I never had any issues.

Comment: just type in the val field

Comment: "live expressions" tool only using for watching variable's values, cant modify in "live expressions"

Comment: you need to break the code

Comment: but i need to change/modify variable's values "while code runinng" without breakpoints

Comment: not possible without writing own code

Answer (score 0):

Try using Expression instead of Live Expression

Comment: Hi Shawnt and Welcome to StackOverflow! I suggest you take a look here on [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), this way you can ensure the most people can take benefit from it!

Comment: thenk you for your answer but this isnt solve the problem
cubeide released new update and new features, now i can do